# não entendi como funciona o valor (self) em "cidade.estado = self " dentro da função adiciona_cidade()

Tags: python-3.x, classes

```
class Estado:

    def __init__(self, nome, sigla):
        self.nome = nome
        self.sigla = sigla
        self.cidades = []

    def adiciona_cidade(self, cidade):
        #essa linha abaixo que eu não entendi o que significa
        cidade.estado = self
        self.cidades.append(cidade)

    def populacao(self):
        #O loop abaixo significa: para cada item de
        #c.populacao (que é: cidade.populacao) em self.cidades.
        return sum([c.populacao for c in self.cidades])

class Cidade:

    def __init__(self, nome, populacao):
        self.nome = nome
        self.populacao = populacao
        self.estado = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cidade (nome=%s, populacao=%d, estado=%s)" %(
            self.nome, self.populacao, self.estado)


# Populações obtidas no site da Wikipédia
# IBGE estimativa 2012
am = Estado("Amazonas", "AM")
am.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Manaus", 1861838))
am.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Parintins", 103828))
am.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Itacoatiara", 89064))

sp = Estado("São Paulo", "SP")
sp.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("São Paulo", 11376685))
sp.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Guarulhos", 1244518))
sp.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Campinas", 1098630))

rj = Estado("Rio de Janeiro", "RJ")
rj.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Rio de Janeiro", 6390290))
rj.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("São Gonçalo", 1016128))
rj.adiciona_cidade(Cidade("Duque de Caixias", 867067))


for estado in  [am, sp, rj]:
    print("Estado: %s Sigla: %s" % (estado.nome, estado.sigla))
    for cidade in estado.cidades:
        print("Cidade: %s População: %d" % (cidade.nome, cidade.população))
    print("População do Estado: %d\n" % estado.população())
```

Answer (score 1):

O `self` em Python é equivalente ao `this` existente em Javascript, Java, C++ e outras - e diz respeito ao próprio objeto.

No caso, você está vendo o `self` dentro de um método da classe Estado - então o self é o próprio estado que tem que ser colocado na cidade. Ele simplesmente preenche essa informação no outro objeto (cidade). .

Ao contrário de outras linguagens, no entanto, o `self` no Python é explícito: ele é recebido como primeiro parâmetro dentro de um método, e em geral é chamado de `self` - e não "aparece do nada" como o `this` nas linguagens que citei. O nome "self" é usado por convenção, e você poderia usar qualquer outro nome (no primeiro parâmetro e na atribuição), que o programa funcionaria do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Então vc quer dizer que "cidade.estado = self" significa a mesma coisa que: "cidade.estado = Estado(nome, sigla)", ou seja, cidade.estado recebe a classe Estado("Amazonas", "AM") com os argumentos configurados ao chamar a classe Estado?, é isso?

Comment: SIm, é isso - mas sem criar um novo objeto - ou seja, você cria um "Amazonas" - `est = Estado("Amazonas", "AM")`, e aí pode chamar o método `est.adiciona_cidade` para mais de uma cidade - todas elas vão ter o mesmo estado amazonas no seu atributo `.estado`. Ou seja ao chamar `est.adiciona_cidade(cid) `, essa linha `cidade.estado = self` dentro do método é equivalente a fazer `cidade.estado = est`